# Is is possible to get an 'index' of a PHP Session

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm working on a booking system (for our own web site) that uses SESSIONs reasonably well.

There are many SESSION variables (with sub-arrays), and I lose track of them periodically. Is there a simple way to get an 'index' (or list) of the 'primary' SESSION variables, such as `$_SESSION['booking']` and `$_SESSION['guest']` without dumping the entire contents of each variable. e.g. I do not (at this point) want to see `$_SESSION['booking']['guestID']`, `$_SESSION['booking']['arrivalDate']` and so on.

I expect that by treating `$_SESSION` as an array there would be a (more complicated) approach, but I'm hoping for something simpler.

Comment: _"There are many SESSION variables (with sub-arrays), and I lose track of them periodically"_ - That sounds more like a bad application design than a session issue.  How much data are you actually storing? Storing large amount of data in sessions can lead to poor performance.

Comment: Treating $_SESSION as an array is totally accurate, because $_SESSION is an array.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson: I didn't mean that the app loses track, just my brain. So for testing purposes it's good to get a periodic reminder of what's there. In absolute terms I'm not storing very much. The biggest item is a calendar array, and I do this to avoid repeated returns to interogate the database.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` **is** an array. That's by design and not even optional. You can [get a list of keys](https://php.net/array_keys) or [loop it](https://php.net/foreach) as with any other array.

Comment: Yes, array_keys gives me what I need and isn't as complicated as I first feared.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function array_keys gave me what I wanted, and is much simpler than I'd feared.

```
$keys = array_keys($_SESSION);
echo 'SESSION keys: '; print_r($keys); echo '<br />';
```

which gave me what I wanted, printing out:

```
SESSION keys: Array ( [0] => pan_image_array [1] => rates [2] => sitevars [3] => availy [4] => query )
```

So next I tried a foreach loop to unset each in turn:

```
    foreach ($keys as $key_value) {
    echo 'Key Value is: ' . $key_value . '<br />';
    unset ($_SESSION[$key_value]);
    }
    // Then print SESSION contents again:
    $keys = array_keys($_SESSION);
    echo 'SESSION keys: '; print_r($keys); echo '<br />';
```

The expectation was that this would show me an empty SESSION at the end, which it did, printing:

```
   SESSION keys: Array ( )
```

That would seem to indicate that the SESSION array was now empty.
But when I went to look at the SESSION in my editor, the first variable (index 0) was still there, as borne out by a second (and subsequent) runs, which printed:

```
  SESSION keys: Array ( [0] => pan_image_array )
  Key Value is: pan_image_array
  SESSION keys: Array ( )
```

So at the end of each cycle I have an apparently empty SESSION array, but on inspection the first index is still there. Why can't I unset the first variable, giving me an 'empty' SESSION? Is it my code, or is an empty SESSION not permitted?

For testing purposes I am trying to achieve an empty SESSION, but without having a new SESSION with a different SID (effectively a new file name) every time I try a new test run. That enables me to keep the SESSION file open in my editor and follow changes.

Comment: I have now worked out why the SESSION variable 'pan_image_array' kept re-appearing. Entirely my fault. But overall this exercise has been useful and a success.